# How to get the package description using python-apt?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to create a graphical program to deal with packages easily for end-users. However, I'm facing a problem in retrieving the package's description beside some other information.

I've seen the python-apt API here and i understood that i have to deal with the `apt.package.Version()` [class](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.package.html#the-version-class).

But when i tried to use it, all what i got is some errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./myprogram", line 6, in <module>
print package.description
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 374, in description
dsc = self._translated_records.long_desc
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 315, in _translated_records
desc_iter = self._cand.translated_description
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translated_description'
```

So, is there any body who can create a running example for the apt.package.Version() class please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `versions` method gives you the list of all available versions. You then have to select one specific version to print the description. For example, for the vim package

```
import apt
cache    = apt.Cache()
pkg      = cache['vim']
versions = pkg.versions
print versions[0].description
```